# WIX C++ Custom Action

Tags: c++, wix, custom-action, name-decoration

I have a basic WIX custom action:

```
        UINT __stdcall MyCustomAction(MSIHANDLE hInstaller)
        {   
            DWORD dwSize=0;
            MsiGetProperty(hInstaller, TEXT("MyProperty"), TEXT(""), &dwSize);
            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }
```

Added to the installer:

```
   <CustomAction Id="CustomActionId" FileKey="CustomDll" DllEntry="MyCustomAction"/>
   <InstallExecuteSequence>
       <Custom Action="CustomActionId" Before="InstallFinalize" />
   </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The problem is that, no matter what i do, the handle hInstaller is not valid. I've set the action to commit, deferred, changed the place in InstallExecute sequence, hInstaller is always not valid.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In what way is it not valid? Are you getting an error back from an API call?

Comment: If i make any call that uses the handle, the function will return Invalid_Handle error message.

Comment: ignoring the handle, is the function itself being called correctly?

Comment: I believe the function was called correctly. Anyway to solve the problem, i've rewritten the setup and the custom dll ( there wasn't a lot of code ), and now it's working ok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to export the called function so MSI can call it using undecorated C style name

Replace your code with this

```
    extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) UINT __stdcall MyCustomAction(MSIHANDLE hInstall);

    extern "C" UINT __stdcall MyCustomAction(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
    {   
        DWORD dwSize=0;
        MsiGetProperty(hInstaller, TEXT("MyProperty"), TEXT(""), &dwSize);
        return ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names), the only way to overcome the mangling of a `__stdcall` is to use:

`#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:SomeFunction=_SomeFunction@@@23mangledstuff#@@@@")`

This creates a second entry in the DLL export table.

Comment: Another way to insure the non-mangled function name is included in the DLL exports, is to EXPORT it in a DEF file, and add it to the Linker Properties (Linker -> Input -> Module Definition File).