# Problem with importing DLL into Inno Setup

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, inno-setup

I am importing an C++ DLL in an Inno Setup install script. The DLL code is as follows:

```c
void __stdcall SetFbParam(
        char *dbFileName,char *dbTableName,char *dbParamName,char *dbParamValue) {
    // of no use here and doesn't change anything
}
```

In the Inno Setup, I import it using

```pascal
procedure FBset(dbFileName,dbTableName,dbParamName,dbParamValue: String;);
    external 'SetFbParam@files:MyDll.dll stdcall setuponly';
```

However, I always get a runtime error during launch of the installer, saying that it cannot import my dll. I tried it with various calling conventions, but it always fails.
If it's of any importance, I'm running Win7 x64 with UAC on (the installer requests rights elevation and crashes after that).

The exact message is:

> Error
> Runtime error (at -1:0):
> Cannot import
> dll:C:\Users\Nevod\AppData\Local\Temp\is-6LOEC.tmp\MyDll.dll

The dll is there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Is `MyDll.dll` 32-bit?

Does `MyDll.dll` depend on any other DLLs in the same directory? If so, you need to list the name(s) of those DLLs after `MyDll.dll` to ensure that they are extracted *before* `MyDll.dll` is loaded, and you likely need the `loadwithalteredsearchpath` option as well. Example from the [help](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll):

```pascal
procedure ADllFunc(hWnd: Integer; lpText, lpCaption: String; uType: Cardinal);
// A.dll depends on B.dll
external 'ADllFunc@files:A.dll,B.dll stdcall loadwithalteredsearchpath';
```

Answer (score 4):

(I know it is old but maybe some other hits this one too)

Most probably the name of the function is mangled in the C++ DLL. I had the same problem and I was able to solve it by recompiling the dll. In short:

If you export from C++ something like:

```c
void __stdcall foo()
```

you will get a function called (Visual Studio):

```
?foo@@YGXXZ
```

To prevent name mangling you should use `extern "C"` directive. Example (Visual Studio)

```c
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) void __stdcall foo()
```

However I have found that Visual Studio will continue to mangle and you get something like:

```
_foo@0
```

The sole way I was able to get clean names is explained here:
[C++ DLL Export: Decorated/Mangled names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names)

And the culprit is indeed `__stdcall`. If you remove that from your declaration:

```c
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) void foo()
```

you will again get a clean export, even without a DEF file. IMO this should be good enough, as the code above declares a "C" exported function and the default calling convention for C is stdcall. However I haven't had the time and disposition to validate this as adding a DEF file is way easier than navigating asm code and check stack pointers :)

Comment: You are a livesaver, I never would've guessed stdcall was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use DLLs in Inno Setup's `[Code]` section please make sure:

- DLL is in 32 bit mode (even if the installer is built for 64bit and is running in 64bit mode)
- exported functions have
  `extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )`
  modifier
- use `cdecl` calling convention because `stdcall` mangles name (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall). Of course it is possible to specify mangled name in Inno Setup import statement. But it seems easier to just use `cdecl`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, do not forget to embed all dependencies of your DLL. Though if it is your DLL, better might be to get rid of (or at least reduce) the dependencies.

- For example when building C++ DLL in  Visual Studio, link the runtime statically, not dynamically.

  In project *Properties*, go to *C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library* and select *Multi-threaded* (not *DLL*).
- There are also tools that can embed other external dependencies.

  See [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189549/850848)