# How do I change the exported name decoration for __stdcall in VC++?

Tags: c++, dll, export, name-decoration

This is how I have my export function declared at the moment:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
Iexport_class* __stdcall GetExported_Class();
```

When VS2008 compiled the source for this, the dll produced contains this under its export table:

```
_GetExported_Class@0
```

For compatibility with other compilers I need the above decoration to look like this instead:

```
GetExported_Class
```

Changing the calling convention to __cdecl will decorate it to the way I want but the convention would be wrong so I can't use that. I need it to be decorated the way __cdecl looks but uses __stdcall instead.

Is there anyway to do this *without* using a .def file? Is there a switch or an option I can pass to the link.exe linker that can make it decorate the export name to the way I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All __stdcall names are decorated this way. I'm amazed that you have some other compiler that won't expect __stdcall exports to be decorated like this. Overriding the linker with .def is pretty much all you can do- unless you want to alter the PE file after production.

Comment: thanks, guess I'll just have to do it the hardway. The 'other' compilers that aren't following the convention happens to be MinGW gcc 4.5.1 and Borland 5.93(C++ Builder 2007). Both of them just spit out the function name as is undecorated -- at least when I cracked it open with a pe viewer to check the export tables.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you don't want to use a .def file, but this is your only option.

The linker supports an export switch, but it cannot be used with functions that are __stdcall annotated:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7k30y2k5.aspx

The def file way is pretty much the only solution.

Comment: mainly because it's extra maintenance work. Trying to see if there was an easier way to streamline this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

You can add `/EXPORT` to the `lib.exe` command-line, or add a `#pragma` to your source file:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:SomeFunction=_SomeFunction@@@23mangledstuff#@@@@")
```

Or even easier: Inside the body of the function use

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__ "=" __FUNCDNAME__)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2805560/280534