# DLL function names using dumpbin.exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have written a .dll library with lots of functions and classes in visual studio 2010.
When I look at the content of the file with:

```
dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS myDll.dll
```

I get long function names with some kind of a function location pointer, which looks like this (second entry in .dll):

```
          2    1 0001100A ?Initialize@codec@codecX@@SANNN@Z = @ILT+5(?Initialize@codec@codecX@@SANNN@Z)
```

This is somehow hard to read, but I saw "nicer" procedure/function list from other .dll-s, like this:

```
141   8C 00002A08 PogoDbWriteValueProbeInfo
```

**How can I make that .dll list look that way?**

*P.S.: my dll source code looks like this:*

```
namespace codecX
{
   class codec
   {
      public:
      static __declspec(dllexport) double Initialize(double a, double b);
      ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to export unmangled names? If you do that then you won't be able to use function overloading. It looks like you are exporting a C++ class. Are you exporting instance methods, constructors etc. Or are all your methods static?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names

Comment: David H., yes my intention was to export human-readable format. Why? I need to pass created .dll to other co-workers and having readable format is essential for good understanding of source code and/or libraries written by someone else. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pull those static member functions into the global address space and then wrap them with
extern "C". This will suppress the C++ name mangling and instead give you C name mangling which is less ugly:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Initialize(double a, double b)
{
    codec::Initialize(a, b);
}
```

and then remove the __declspec(dllexport) on your static member functions:

```
class codec
{
    public:
        static double Initialize(double a, double b);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is called **name-mangling** and happens when you compile C++ with a C++-compiler.
In order to retain the "humand-readable" names you'll have to use `extern "C"` when declaring and defining your classes and your functions. i.e.

```
extern "C" void myFunction(int, int);
```

See [here](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/mixing.html) and also google `mixing C and C++`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Let's agree I forgot about it, okay ;) ? But you are right, of course.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is C++ mangling of function names.

In case this function needs to be kept as a C++ function you can post process the `dumpbin.exe` output to obtain the normal function name using the utility `undname.exe`.

Supplied with Microsoft Visual Studio is a utility for undecorating C++ mangled function names called `undname.exe`.

It can be used as follows:

```
C:\>undname ?func1@a@@AAEXH@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "?func1@a@@AAEXH@Z"
is :- "private: void __thiscall a::func1(int)"
```