# Get exported functions from a x86 DLL

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll, x86

Is there any way to get a list of the exported functions from a x86 DLL in C#? I know of Mono.Cecil that can decompile .NET DLLs to provide a list of the types/members, but searches come up blank when I search for x86 DLLs.

I'm looking at building a "DLL explorer" tool that lists the exported functions, enabling me to get a quick peek into DLLs and see the functionality.

Similar:

- [C++ DLL Export: Decorated/Mangled names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names)
- [DLL function names using dumpbin.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090196/dll-function-names-using-dumpbin-exe)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446532.aspx
- [Finding arguments that go with methods in C++ dll's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229333/finding-arguments-that-go-with-methods-in-c-dlls)

Comment: You can use [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). or `dumpbin /exports Event.dll`.

Comment: Nice but does it have an API or can it be called from C#? The webpage lists nothing for "API" and only GUI options can be set via command line.

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try converting https://stackoverflow.com/a/4354755/613130 . It is written in C++ and uses some Windows API, but it should be possible to rewrite it in C#.

Or you can catch the output of `dumpbin /exports YourDll.dll`

Mmmmh... I've taken a look, and the ImageHlp methods are probably a little C#-unfriendly... and they aren't Unicode compatible. :-(

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128453/613130 there is another method, that seems to be a little simpler.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend having a look ILspy, this works on reflection to examine an assembly.

http://ilspy.net/

if you are using Visual Studio you can install this through the extension managager...Tools/Extension Manager/ search for ILspy

As this is C# not C++ unlike dependency walker this will not just show you the interface but the entire code base.

More generally here is an example of how reflection works:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx