# How to call from C# simple function in C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

i have a simple function in c++ (not a method of a class)

```
__declspec(dllexport) extern "C" void __stdcall TestFunc();
```

i try to call it from c#:

```
[DllImport("ImportTest.dll")]  
public static extern void TestFunc();  

...  

TestFunc();
```

It throws an "entry point could't be found" exception.

Whats wrong?

Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try (guessing, that DLL is written in VS)

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall TestFunc();
```

That's:

- `__declspec(dllexport)` to notify compiler, that this function is to be exported from the DLL;
- `extern "C"` mainly to prevent [function name decorations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names);
- `__stdcall`, because this is default calling convention if you specify none in `[DllImport]` directive.

In the future, you can check if your function is exported from DLL using [Dll export viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html).

Comment: Sry, spook, my demo code was incomplete, i corrected it. In the original it is defined correctly. I corrected my question now.

Comment: Have you actually used `Dll export viewer` to check, what is the  name of your exported function? If .NET can not find the entry point it means, that it can not find specified function name in DLL export list. I bet, that VS decorated name of your function despite `extern "C"`.

Comment: In the original DLL Export Viewer didn't show any exported function. Changing it to "extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void TestFunc();" the function is shown. Great tool! Thx for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In C++ function , at header(if your function is declared in header) add

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void TestFunc();
```

at the function definition use

```
_declspec(dllexport) void TestFunc()
{

}
```

At C# side,you need to declare a function like

```
[DllImport(@"ImportTest.dll",
                 EntryPoint = "TestFunc",
                 ExactSpelling = false,
                 CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            static extern void NewTestFunc()
```

Now use , NewTestFunc()