# Exporting ASM function from DLL - Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, dll, dllexport

I have created Dll project.
I created myasm.asm file that has one function:

```
 .486
.model flat, stdcall
.code
MyProc1 proc x: DWORD, y: DWORD
    xor eax,eax
//......//
    ret
MyProc1 endp
    end
```

There is my heade file:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

#ifdef LAB1DLL_EXPORTS
#define LAB1DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LAB1DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
    LAB1DLL_API int _stdcall MyProc1(DWORD x, DWORD y);
}
```

And dllMain (beging of it)"

```
#define LAB1DLL_EXPORTS 1
#include "Lab1Dll.h"
```

Im my test application in wich I want to use that dll and it's exported function I have:

```
#include "Lab1Dll.h"
```

But my dll is not exporting my MyProc1 function. If I add "normal" function to that DLL and exprot it it is avilable in my Test application and DLL compilation process produces lib file.

Without "normal" functions I don't get .lib file. And I can't link to that library.

How to make that exported function work? Or how to make it export in the first place?

UPDATE:
I saw that adding .def file with below contens works perfect. But then. I shouldn't be doing it. That is what __declspec(dllexport) should do for me?

```
LIBRARY

EXPORTS

MyProc1
```

Comment: Might have something to do with decorated/mangled names; check with `dumpbin`. Try defining the proc with its decorated/mangled name in `myasm.asm` (but not in the header and C sources). Other suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names

Comment: @Ruud How? I'm asking about that "decoration".

Answer (score 4):

The masm equivalent to `__declspec(dllexport)` is `EXPORT` after `proc`

So this will add the .drectve section to the *.obj file that masm produces and will be processed by the linker

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.code
MyProc1 proc EXPORT x: DWORD, y: DWORD
    xor eax,eax
    ret
MyProc1 endp
end
```

Also if you declare `MyProc1` as `extern "C"` in your header file it's

`MyProc1 proc C EXPORT x: DWORD, y: DWORD`

otherwise it's

`MyProc1 proc stdcall EXPORT x: DWORD, y: DWORD`

to make sure the name-mangling matches

Comment: well this is awkward, didn't see that this was an old question bumped from 2014

Comment: That's OK.  I was going to answer it anyways, knowing it was an old question, though with a not as good an answer (I didn't realize there was an EXPORT keyword to PROC.) . I would add though that the reason why `__declspec(dllexport)` doesn't work for the original poster is because it needs to be used on the definition of the function, not the declaration.

Comment: @RossRidge yeah, the dllexport can not work with masm since you can't include the *.h into your *.asm file. Also the EXPORT thing is not very well documented apparently, but I just thought I'd add it for completeness

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when trying to use from another module (DLL/EXE) an assembly function exported from a DLL. From the linker error I figured out that the importing module was trying to access e.g. `__impl_SRFlushCache` function instead of `SRFlushCache` function as it is declared in the exporting module's header file and defined in assembly file. So something was adding `__impl_` prefix nevertheless I declared the function as `extern "C"` to avoid any mangling.

I solved the problem by adding a module definition (.def) file to the exporting module and listing my assembly function there like below:

```
LIBRARY SRPlatform
EXPORTS
  SRFlushCache
```

---

For reference:

Function declaration in a header file:

```
#ifdef SRPLATFORM_EXPORTS
#define SRPLATFORM_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SRPLATFORM_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // SRPLATFORM_EXPORTS

SRPLATFORM_API void __fastcall SRFlushCache(const void *pFirstCl, const void *pLimCl, const size_t clSize);
```

Function definition in the .asm file:

```
_DATA SEGMENT

_DATA ENDS

_TEXT SEGMENT

PUBLIC SRFlushCache

; RCX=pFirstCl
; RDX=pLimCl
; R8=clSize
SRFlushCache PROC

SRFlushCache_Loop:
  clflushopt byte ptr [RCX]
  add RCX, R8
  cmp RCX, RDX ; RCX-RDX
  jl SRFlushCache_Loop
  ret

SRFlushCache ENDP

_TEXT ENDS

END
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, first you create a name.def file with your definitions in your project. Then you go to the project Properties > Linker > Input > Module Definition File. Add the name.def file to that property. It should export then. (If anyone runs into how to add the definition file to the project, like I did.)

Answer (score 0):

> There are four methods for exporting a definition, listed in
>   recommended order of use:
>
> - __declspec(dllexport) in the source code
> - An EXPORTS statement in a .def file
> - An /EXPORT specification in a LINK command
> - A comment directive in the source code, of the form #pragma comment(linker, "/export: definition ").

Source

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=vs-2017

Origin

- http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=5150.0