# DLL bad function names

Tags: c, dll

I'm working on a DLL which contains function `DLLEXPORT void* GetBase(HANDLE hProc)` and when I compile it, I open it with Dependency Walker, and there's no function with name "GetBase". I can see only "?GetBase@@YAPAXPAX@Z". What's wrong with this? I'm using Visual C++ 2013 and I compiled it as release.

Comment: You are building your code as C++.  Is the file extension .cpp or .c?

Comment: The file extension is ".cpp".

Comment: This is entirely normal, a C++ compiler will *decorate* a function name.  Necessary so that overloaded methods will have different linkage names.  Use `extern "C"` to suppress it.  Don't suppress it, it is a good way to avoid trouble when you change the function declaration and not update the code that uses it.

Comment: Well, I used extern C and opened the file in Dependency walker. Now it doesnt show up anything.

Comment: The other way is to just rename the file extension to .c and build it as a C DLL.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing "wrong" with your function. It's been "mangled"; in other words, the compiler's added type information to your function name. This is how C++ supports overloading: functions with the same name, but taking different parameters, will have different mangled function names.

Your DLL might also have [debug info attached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2805812/2245528), which could be another source of name mangling.

With all that said, the "c" tag on your question is bothersome; C doesn't have overloading and as such doesn't need name mangling.