# How to avoid Visual C++ from mangling the names of my DLL functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, vb6

I have the same problem [exposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names). I'm using Visual C++ Express 2010.

I tried declaring extern "C", and changing the options Project + Properties, Linker, Debugging, Generate Debug Info = No. My function names are mangled on every compilation.

[After reading the answer of jjones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697372/111110) I changed the calling convention from StdCall to Cdecl, and then my function names are correct in the compiled dll. But I need the StdCall because I'm using this dll from VB6 (Vb6 protests when using other calling convention). So, everytime I compile with StdCall calling convention, my function names get mangled again.

How can I avoid my function names from being mangled with StdCall calling convention? or Is there a way to call a function in a Dll with cdecl calling convention from VB6?

Comment: If the name looks like `_function@16` then it's correct.

Comment: I get names with that format, but VB6 complains about the _ and @ characters :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [reading and reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I found out that (maybe) there's no way to avoid name mangling with StdCall calling convention.

I wanted to call my functions from VB6, so here's a workaround that actually works:
Declaring the functions with alias:

```
Declare Function prettyname Lib "mydll.dll" Alias "_prettyname@16" () As Integer
```

Of course, it is better to use `extern "C"`, so the names don't get horribly mangled.