# c++ dll export mangled name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, dllexport

I'm trying to export a function called `CreateGameClient` and when I do dumpbin /exports I get this instead `?CreateGameClient@@YAXXZ` and the program I'm injecting the DLL into needs `CreateGameClient` and not `?CreateGameClient@@YAXXZ`

And I'm using Visual Studio 2012 if that helps

This is my code ExpFunc.h

```
#ifndef INDLL_H
#define INDLL_H

 #ifdef EXPORTING_DLL
  __declspec(dllexport) void CreateGameClient() ;
#else
  __declspec(dllimport) void CreateGameClient() ;
#endif

#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#define EXPORTING_DLL
#include "ExpFunc.h"

void WriteLogFile(const char*);
void CreateGameClient2(int);

char* logStr;
char* CGCNStr;
char buf[250];
DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            logStr = "Attached To: %d";
            sprintf(buf, logStr, pid);
            WriteLogFile(buf);
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            logStr = "Detached To: %d";
            sprintf(buf, logStr, pid);
            WriteLogFile(buf);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void CreateGameClient()
{
    CreateGameClient2(2);
}

void CreateGameClient2(int num)
{
    std::stringstream temp_str;
    temp_str << (num);
    std::string str = temp_str.str();
    const char* cstr2 = str.c_str();

    sprintf(buf, cstr2, pid);
    WriteLogFile(buf);
}

void WriteLogFile(const char* szString)
{
    FILE* pFile = fopen("logFile.txt", "a");
    fprintf(pFile, "%s\n",szString);
    fclose(pFile);

}
```

I have tried [C++ DLL Export: Decorated/Mangled names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804893/c-dll-export-decorated-mangled-names)

but still didn't work

Comment: what solution from linked question you've tried? `extern "C"`?

Comment: [Demangling](http://demangler.com/) of `?CreateGameClient@@YAXXZ` actually gives `void __cdecl CreateGameClient(void)` which is correct in your case.

Comment: I tried Hans Passant solution didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must decorate both declaration and definition of a function with `extern "C" __declspec(...)` otherwise you should be getting a warning about non consistent linking definition and erratic behaviour.

Comment: You have CreateGameClient() in the .cpp file too. Add extern "C" __declspec() to its signature to make it look exactly like in the header file.